# Can't get cloudstor:azure Docker plugin to work with latest versions of Docker/plugin

Tags: azure, docker, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm attempting to create a docker volume using the cloudstor:azure docker plugin on a Ubuntu 18 VM in Azure.

I managed to get this working once on a VM with this Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.1
 Git commit:        2d0083d
 Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:20:06 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.1
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Wed Aug 14 19:41:23 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

And installing build azure-v17.03.0-ce of the plugin.  However That's not the default version of Docker that comes with the Ubuntu 18 VM image so at some point I must have upgraded something but can't reproduce this.

So I tried to upgrade Docker and the plugin to 19.03, I now get different errors when installing the plugin or trying to enable it:

```
docker plugin enable cloudstor:azure
Error response from daemon: failed to listen to abstract unix socket "/containerd-shim/plugins.moby/7bee13f0a815242cfcf1bf5d715ab1bc4d687c482e5ac0051aae90061980f8bb/shim.sock": listen unix ?/containerd-shim/plugins.moby/7bee13f0a815242cfcf1bf5d715ab1bc4d687c482e5ac0051aae90061980f8bb/shim.sock: bind: permission denied: unknown
```

I've noticed on the Docker version that does work there no 'ce' indicate Community Edition, not sure if that matters.

If I update Docker daemon to 18.09.9 and use docker4x/cloudstor:azure-v17.03.0-ce I can get the plugin to work correctly.  But I cant get this working with any other versions of Docker or the plugin.

How do you get the cloudstor:azure Docker plugin working on a Ubuntu VM in Azure with latest versions of Docker and the plugin?